# Input transition

Tags: html, css, transition

I try to animate my search button.
When you click on it, it should expand and slide to the side.
The animation is no problem in css, but in front of the search bar is a div, which does not follow the expanding search bar.

```
<form>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>

form{
  float:right;
}

input[type=search] {
  background: #E75757 url(http://nerdlove.de/Blog/img/search_icon.svg) no-repeat 15px center;
    background-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
    text-indent:-999px;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 150px;
  background-position: -30px;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

.test{
    float:left;
}

.test:before{
    content: no-close-quote;
  border-top: 40px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 18px solid #E75757;
  float: right;
  right: 55px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Nerd/pen/e1e66d0e4743453eb5a05125655b8345?editors=110)

I would add the :before to the input. But it is not possible in css.

**Edit**
[HERE IS WHAT I WANT](http://media.giphy.com/media/3oEdv8gXs5AQWahUKA/giphy.gif)

Comment: Do you want the .test div to stick to the left of the input[type=text] as the input expands? It's difficult understanding what you are trying to achieve, maybe revise your question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just position the `.test` element as `relative` and the `:before` to `right: 0;`.

```
.test{
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}

.test:before{
    content: no-close-quote;
  border-top: 40px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 18px solid #E75757;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzsf16dL/)

Comment: Nice catch, I was trying to fix it and didn't realize of the position absolute of the before pseudoelement, lol.